# webkit automated web testing

Tags: webkit, qtwebkit

I need to automate web testing for a non-standard web browser built on top of webkit. 
This web browser is available on a non-desktop device (e.g. mobile). Please suggest me some ways to automate it.

A normal test case includes following setup, action and verify steps.
setup: open the browser.
action: open an internal url
verify: page rendered successfully on browser.

I don't have much access to this device, I can get the logs from serial connection and can do screen capture.

As a first step, I was thinking to use capture and replay approach where I will first capture all the images and later compare with these stored images. But this approach does not look scalabale and prone to time consuming.

Please suggest me something to achieve this automation using webkit.

Comment: Why are you testing on hardware?  Use a simulator, that's what they're for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try http://sikuli.org/

run a server that has the ability like VNC server, then your test tool run as a VNC client which is visually remote controller running on PC, then use Sikuli to automate on the test tool which in the end pass all actions to the device and verify result on PC.